# How to avoid shared pointers in C++ caused by try/catch?

Tags: c++, reference, try-catch, shared-ptr

I use shared pointers because of variable can only live in block where it was created.

```
int main(void) {

    std::shared_ptr<project::log::Log> log;

    try {
        log = make_shared<annmu::log::Log>("error.log"); // can throw eception
    }
    catch(std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Error\n\n";
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I would like to avoid shared pointers and created code more simple. Something like following code (*not working code*).

```
int main(void) {

    project::log::Log log; // can throw eception

    try {
        log = project::log::Log("error.log"); // can throw eception
    }
    catch(std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Error\n\n";
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Is it good way to avoid shared pointers? Is it more efficient solution? In second solution the object is created two times.

Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Why not simply define the `log` variable inside the `try` block?

Comment: Because it can throw exception.

Comment: Yes, which is why you create it in the `try` block to begin with, right? So why not simply define the variable normally inside the `try` block? As in `try { project::log::Log log("error.log"); /* Other code... */ }`

Comment: is it good practice to write everything to try{}? and do nested try {} catch {}?

Comment: If you're nesting try/catch blocks, you most likely have a structural problem and need to rethink.

Comment: @Parzival: C++ needs less catch blocks than many languages, because there's a lot you do in destructors. That's usually cleaner; the compiler ensures they're executed in reverse order. You need `catch` for the occasional case where the default behavior is insufficient.

Comment: If the variable "can only live in block where it was created", then declare it in that block. This is really unrelated to exception handling; you should normally avoid declaring a variable in a broader scope than where it is relevant. (On a side note, returning `0` - the "success" code - on failure is not usually a good idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good practice to avoid using shared pointers, unless you are actually sharing the pointer. You could use a unique_ptr as a drop in replacement.
It is not a bad idea to have a non-throwing constructor, which constructs the object into a valid-empty state. Handling exceptions in construction is always more complex than handling an exception during an operation. Complex solutions require more brain-power, and brain-power is a scarce resource in large programs
So in general, I think everything you say is right. I like to think of objects as having 6 distinct stages.

- Allocation
- Construction
- Initialisation
- Active // Do useful functions, etc
- Destruction
- Deallocation

For simple objects reducing this to just construction/destruction is just convenient, and reduces how much you have to think about. For heavy-weight objects it makes sense to separate out each stage and make them separately testable. You get better error handling and error reporting this way (IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

I would first define an interface for my logging, so I can create loggers in multiple ways (you will need this for unit testing). And then catch the exception by `const` reference. To be able to use the polymorphism of the interface a `std::unique_ptr` to that interface is needed (but at least it isn't a shared_ptr).

Full example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class log_itf
{
public:
    virtual void log(const std::string& str) const = 0; // logging should not modify anything
    virtual ~log_itf() = default;
};

class logger :
    public log_itf
{
public:
    logger(const std::string& /*filename*/)
    {
        // let this throw if it fails.
        // throw std::runtime_error("file not found");
    }

    void log(const std::string& str) const override
    {
        std::cout << str << "\n";
    }
};

// a logger that does nothing.
class null_logger :
    public log_itf
{
public:
    void log(const std::string&) const override {}
};

// example of a class that wants to use logging
class class_that_uses_logging
{
public:
    explicit class_that_uses_logging(const log_itf& logger) :
        m_logger{ logger }
    {
        m_logger.log("constructor of class that uses logging");
    }

private:
    const log_itf& m_logger;
};

// helper factory methods that do the typecasting to interface for you
std::unique_ptr<log_itf> create_logger(const std::string& filename)
{
    return std::make_unique<logger>(filename);
}

std::unique_ptr<log_itf> create_null_logger()
{
    return std::make_unique<null_logger>();
}


int main()
{
    try
    {
        // for production code
        auto logger = create_logger("log.txt");

        // for test code
        // auto logger = create_null_logger();

        logger->log("Hello World\n");

        // or pass logging to some other class
        // this pattern has a name and is called dependency
        // injection and is very useful for big projects 
        // (with unit tests)
        class_that_uses_logging object(*logger);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) // always catch by const&
    {
        std::cout << "error : " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right it isn't needed. updated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

- `std::shared_ptr<>`
- `make_shared`

You could be alternatively using:

- `std::unique_ptr<>`
- `make_unique`

`shared_ptr` is slow and susceptible to problems.

In this case, you would need to use `std::unique_ptr<>`, considering that it is not needed in order to take ownership of an object while storing a pointer to another object.

In retrospect, you don't need to share ownership.